# Pandas calculate "bars since high"

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate a rolling "bars since high" number that resets as new highs are made in Pandas. I can calculate the rolling highs but not the number of rows since that happened.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,10,3,4,5,25],columns=['price'])
df['high'] = df['price'].rolling(window=100000,min_periods=1).max()
```

in this case, the desired output would be:

```
df['barssincehigh'] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0]
```

But I can't think of a way of calculating number of rows since the most recent high.

Comment: Your question needs to be updated to include a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output

Comment: @itprorh66 how is that?

Comment: Do you specifically want a window of 100000?  Or is this just an arbitrary large number?

Comment: arbitrary cuz im a n00b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your window is an arbitrary large number, and you actually want to calculate the cumulative maximum across the dataframe, you can use:

```py
df["high"] = df.price.cummax()
# replaces:
df['high'] = df['price'].rolling(window=100000,min_periods=1).max()
```

To calculate counts for each new maximum:

```py
df["bars_since_high"] = df.groupby("high").cumcount()
```

This grouping will work because there will necessarily be unique groups, as each maximum ***must*** be greater than all previous maximums.